# how to detect radiobutton checked conditon in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

how to recognize selected radiobutton value or check condition. i have been developing some below codes but i can not  realise why if i check IsPerDay, 
IsPerDay not return to controller checked. how to see radiobutton check or unchecked in controller?

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EveryDay() {
        document.getElementById('RdIsPerDay').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('RdIsPerWeekDay').checked = false;
        document.getElementById("txtPerDay").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("lblPerday").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    function EveryWeekDay() {
        document.getElementById('RdIsPerDay').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('RdIsPerWeekDay').checked = true;
        document.getElementById("txtPerDay").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("lblPerday").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning any value to the radio button. Add this to your code and check :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EveryDay() {
    document.getElementById('RdIsPerDay').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('RdIsPerWeekDay').checked = false;
    //add this to your code
    document.getElementById('RdIsPerDay').value= true;
    document.getElementById('RdIsPerWeekDay').value= false;

    document.getElementById("txtPerDay").style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById("lblPerday").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
function EveryWeekDay() {
    document.getElementById('RdIsPerDay').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('RdIsPerWeekDay').checked = true;
    //add this to your code
    document.getElementById('RdIsPerDay').value= false;
    document.getElementById('RdIsPerWeekDay').value= true;

    document.getElementById("txtPerDay").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("lblPerday").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```